# Intel OpenMP installation issues

Tags: linux, openmp

I am trying to install the Intel OpenMP Runtime on my Linux box in the context of enabling `OpenMP` support for the `clang` compiler. I am following the following guide: http://clang-omp.github.io/.

I've gotten to the point where the compiler is built, recognizes `-fopenmp`, and knows where `omp.h` is. Now the only thing missing is that it can't find `-liomp5`, which I assume is the Intel OpenMP runtime. The instructions at the aforementioned website say that I need to do this:

> To run (rather than just compile) code you need to get and build an Intel® OpenMP* Runtime Library.

So I downloaded the runtime, and was presented with the following choice of compilers in the readme:

```
Supported Architectures: IA-32 architecture, Intel(R) 64, and 
Intel(R) Many Integrated Core Architecture

              -----------------------------------------------------------  
              |           icc/icl            |           gcc            |
--------------|------------------------------|--------------------------|
| Linux* OS   |            Yes(1,5)          |         Yes(2,4)         | 
| OS X*       |            Yes(1,3,4)        |          No              |
| Windows* OS |            Yes(1,4)          |          No              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

(1) On IA-32 architecture and Intel(R) 64, icc/icl versions 12.x are 
    supported (12.1 is recommended).
(2) gcc version 4.6.2 is supported.
(3) For icc on OS X*, OS X* version 10.5.8 is supported.
(4) Intel(R) Many Integrated Core Architecture not supported.
(5) On Intel(R) Many Integrated Core Architecture, icc/icl versions 13.0 
    or later are required.
```

Which, unless my reading comprehension skills are worse than I thought, suggest that I can choose to use `gcc 4.6.2` for compiling the runtime. Unfortunately, when I proceed to build it, I get:

```
$ make compiler=gcc
[...]
----- 1/1 --- making lib inc common -----
Build  : 00000000 (development)
check-tools.pl: (!) No "gfortran" found in PATH.
check-tools.pl: (!) No "icc" found in PATH.
check-tools.pl: (!) No "icpc" found in PATH.
check-tools.pl: (!) No "ifort" found in PATH.

../../tools/src/common-checks.mk:59: *** Development tools not found: icc, icpc, ifort.  Stop.
```

I am really at a loss here. Has anyone had *any* success using `clang-omp`, and is this step of building the Intel runtime actually required? I must be really bad at following instructions and it just isn't working out, I need some assistance. Thank you.

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler suite which contains several *optional* elements, including `gfortran`. Maybe you should install `gfortran`?

Comment: @RobinGreen I just tried and it just prints this: `Development tools not found: icc, icpc, ifort.  Stop.`. And the Intel compiler suite costs a fortune, so I'd be surprised if it was required to build it.

Comment: @RobinGreen You were right. I needed to install `gfortran`, it works with some modifications. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it (and maybe it should be put into the readme.. the error message is very misleading).

Comment: There are a couple of ways that you can contact us (the OpenMP runtime team at Intel) directly, which would likely get you a result faster than asking here. Either via http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-open-source-openmp-runtime-library or the LLVM OPenmp-dev maillist http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/openmp-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message is the key one. You need to install `gfortran`, which is the optional Fortran compiler that is part of the GNU Compiler Collection (which is what GCC, the project, now stands for - as opposed to gcc, the executable, which is a C compiler).